# What are the different items rarity colors, and what do they worth at the PNJ's?

Tags: path-of-exile

So far, I've found a bunch of grey, two blue and two yellow/gold items.  [This page](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Rarity) talks about 4 levels of rarity: normal, magic, rare and unique.  But there are no information about the colors.  My guess:

- grey = normal,
- blue = magic,
- gold = rare,
- ???? = unique

Also, I couldn't find a "pattern" of increasing currency while selling items to the PNJ's.  For example, I sold a normal bow, the PNJ gave me two pieces of scroll (wisdom).  Then I sold a magic bow and received...  two pieces of scroll (wisdom).  Maybe the magic bow was a really weak one ?

Comment: Did you identify the magic bow? Unidentified items sell for less. Although the extra gains in identifying a blue rarity item for sale seem rarely worth using a scroll of wisdom, for higher rarity I recommend identifying before selling as I've frequently doubled my sale value (8+ fragments total early game).

Comment: Yep, in the meantime I got a better understanding of the recipes system ;) thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The item colors are:

- white = normal,
- blue = magic,
- yellow = rare,
- orange = unique
- any of the four colors with border = map with according rarity
- gold = special (orbs, scrolls)
- dark green = active skill gems
- light green = quest items

You can find a list of known vendor recipes [here (spoilers!)](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/15223).

Comment: Also: green=quest item

Comment: @Jonas Thanks, forgot quest items and skill gems - updated.

Answer (score 0):

Items and their values are evaluated a bit more evenly in PoE because:

1. You can UPGRADE normal to magic.
2. You can UPGRADE normal to rare.
3. You can UPGRADE normal to random rarity.
4. You can UPGRADE magic to rare.
5. You can REFORGE stats on normal/rare items.
6. You can UPGRADE the quality of items/gems/flasks.
7. You can change the gem slot colors on items.
8. You can even RANDOMIZE the property values.

So as you see... unlike Diablo 3, an item is actually valuable based on how you use it, which I think is their intention, and STATS of weapons really do matter more than rarity or color because you can easily upgrade your strongest items.

[PoE Currency Items and Descriptions](http://www.pathofexile.com/item-data/currency)

Comment: Correct on all points and good information, but does not answer the exact question asked by the op.